# POST request in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, post, webclient, httprequest

I am trying to get some data from the user and send it to my server for logging purposes. I was able to do it easily with jquery for my website. When I try to write a windows app for the same I am clueless as to how to post the data to my server.

So far I have fetched the data from the user and I am trying to use `OpenWriteAsync` function of webclient to send it to my server. I understand how `OpenWriteAsync` function works but I am not able to figure out how to send my own data.

My php script in my server will get values with name "FILENAME" and "FTIME" like,

$fname = $_POST['FILENAME'];
$time = $_POST['FTIME'];

So I have got this information from the user in two different string variables in c# inside my app. Now how do I send this to my server so that my php script gets this value and logs it inside my server.

I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at UploadData method.

The way you use it something like this:

```
UploadData("http://abc.com","POST", "data in byte array");
```

Note: you need to convert data to byte array

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktfa4fek(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: actually you can uploadstring too, so you don't have to convert it into byte array...

Comment: I tried it. The request does goes to the server but without any data. I even get a response from my server but it indicates that I didn't receive any information from the app and the file that I am updating is not updated.

Comment: `wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.edjai.com/ResearchTest/getDetails.php"), "POST", content);`

Where content is ,
`String content = "UNAME=\""+username+"\"&PASS=\""+pass+"\"";`

Comment: have you set content-type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: Sorry didn't update the post. I actually solved it. The problem was with headers. Once I set the headers everything was working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the [`ContentType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property in the `HTTPWebRequest` object.

Comment: But I don't understand. If webclient is used to make httprequest and if the default method is POST then there should be a way to post my data to the server. I am not able to figure out the data to the server so that the php script take can take it up.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. When you send the stream to the specified `url` using the `method` property set to `post`. It should work just like any post request from your html forms. Take a look at [`HTTPWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7x3zz2(v=VS.95).aspx) which extends `WebReqest`. You should be able to set the method property to `post`.